# count the points in a group - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Let me start with explaining the fiddle I have provided. 
https://jsfiddle.net/abcdlearner/a4y3cge4/1

In the right most part of the chart, there are four bubbles clubbed together. So When I mouseover any of the bubbles in that group, I should get the count as four always. because the group contains four bubbles. Whereas, in the fiddle, it will show different count when hovering over different bubbles.

In short, for instance, if there are 8 bubbles linked/clubbed together, it should show the count as 8 when hovering over any of the bubbles in that group of 8. I need the group count, instead of the count of the bubbles intersecting the hovered bubble. This can be achieved through recursion I suppose. But I am stuck with this.  Any timely help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
series: [{
      tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function () {
    var _this = this;
    var overlapCount = this.series.data.reduce(function (sum, point) {
        return sum + (point !== _this && areOverlapping(_this, point));
    }, 0) + 1;
    return 'Overlapping bubbles: ' + overlapCount;
}
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to count all bubbles that are `chained` together. I created recursive code that collect all bubbles that are chained in one group and returns them in an array. Take a look at the example I posted below.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/m53tevbq/

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your script needed some recursion.

You wasn't very far from the desired result. My logic follows the transitivity relation:

[image: simple transitivity relation]

So imagine `A`, `B` and `C` are chart bubbles. If `A` overlaps `B` that overlaps `C` (`A` doesn't overlaps `C`), the total amount of overlapping bubbles is 3.

So `A` doesn't "know" `C`, but both are overlapping `B`.

If you have any questions about the logic or the code, feel free to ask. I put some comments into the code to explain you what I've done.

Finally, [here is your working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/a4y3cge4/3/).

Comment: Hey thanks much for the efforts. Please see the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4y3cge4/5/

Comment: Oh right, the problem is that my example takes only the element with the higher amount of overlapping siblings and set it to other bubbles of a same group.